# Java String ordering inside an android Textview

Tags: java, android

I have a name like this

```
"3":"BBB, AAA, Location","2":"BBB, AAA, Location,"1":"BBB, AAA, Location"
```

I want the result like this

```
1. BBB, AAA, Location
2. BBB, AAA, Location
3. BBB, AAA, Location
```

I tried with this

```
Name.setText(Name.replace("\"", "").replace(":", ". "));
```

I know that `/n` will be use for new line. But, Still I bit confused How can I achieve that.

Comment: It looks like a JSON string to me, why not use a library to convert it to a Java Object or array? GSON seems like a common choice: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Yes,It was parsed from a JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] newText = Name.split("\",\""); //it returns an array of strings
for (int i=0; i<newText.length; i++)
    newText[i] = newText[i].replace("\"", "").replace(":", ". ");
Arrays.sort(newText);
String ultimateText = "";
for (String s : newText)
    ultimateText = ultimateText+s+"\n";
Name.setText(ultimateText);
```

It's quite tricky. import Arrays.

Comment: Even if he formats the string correctly the items will be out of order.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But Yes, I need to order the data.

Comment: Right. (: There's a way: he can `Name.split("\",\"")` then replace, and order with some comparator, then rebuild it and `setText()`. But i think is more efficient with some JSON library, as you and @HunterMcMillen stated.

Comment: returned [Ljava.lang.String;@40e7e4e8 I tried, Arrays.toString(). But, not working.

Comment: @AntonelloGatto Please check

Comment: @user2579475 updated, i missed `newText[i]`, then you have to import Arrays class. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As @HunterMcMillen stated you should use a Json libary, Gson is a good choice but can be a little advanced, maybe try http://json.org/java/ there are free librarys to use the JSON string.

Using any JSON library what you would do is get a JSON Object or array of those 3 options, put them in a array list and sort them. Then add it to your output formatted. I would start with changing the way you store that string you posted by storing as a JSON Object (be it Gson or Json.org). Then go from there.